# Anchor element doesn't open the href on EDGE when svg is used

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<a target="_blank" href={this.props.FacebookUrl}>
  <svg className="icon svg-facebook">
     <use xlinkHref={'/Content/icons/sprite/icons-common.svg#facebook'} />
  </svg> 
</a>

Generated Code:


<a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-reactid=".dzu29bnjgg.0.0.0.2.0.1.0.0.0">
  <svg class="icon svg-facebook" data-reactid=".dzu29bnjgg.0.0.0.2.0.1.0.0.0.0">
    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/Content/icons/sprite/icons-common.svg#facebook" data-reactid=".dzu29bnjgg.0.0.0.2.0.1.0.0.0.0.0">
    </use>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Clicking on the Anchor opens the Facebook Url besides on EDGE

What's the problem?

Comment: Could you also paste the generated code please

Comment: Try to give the anchor `display: inline-block` or something like that. Or try to add some text and see if that works maybe you can narrow down the issue. I don't have edge so can't help you test

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Give the svg the attribute `focusable="false"`and tell me if that fixes it.

Comment: sorry.  thought it might be a bubbling thing in EDGE.

Comment: @Alon have you tried this in IE 11, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari?

Comment: Sounds like an EDGE bug.  File a bug report here: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/content/content.aspx?ContentID=29582